# How to do git pull for all sub-directories in a folder?(In Windows )

Tags: windows, git, powershell, cmd, git-pull

I have a git directory, I want to do `git pull` for all sub directories, sub sub directory and so on, how to do that in windows command prompt or powershell ?

**NOTE**: I know about similar questions, but none of them work for me as some are for linux and rest only do git pull for `.git` folders inside master folder(i.e. `depth = 1`), I want depth = ∞

Comment: If parent dir that you are in is already a git repo, why the need to run this in all sub dirs? It will do the needful on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Good morning!

In powershell, recursiving subdirectories is as easy as supplying the parameter of `-recurse`. For example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\me -Filter "*.git" -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%a/.git" cmd /c "cd /d %a && git pull"
```

it loops over all subdirectories recursively, and check if it contains `.git` directory, if yes it runs the command in this found path